# UITableView header that stays at top

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'd like to have a tableview header that can remain at the top of the table, even when the user has scrolled down. I tried using a section header for this, but my table has multiple sections so I can't guarantee that one particular header will be at the top.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your parent view, add the table view and a separate "header" view. Position the table view origin below the header view's origin.